# XSLT nested looping and sum

Tags: xslt

I don't have knowledge on XSLTs with nested looping and keeping values global. Below is what I want to achieve.

Standard (Hierarchy 1)
Student (Hierarchy 2)
Results (Hierarchy 3) -> This calls a procedure to look at every result(mark) of all subjects and display when the mark is above 40.

Now the requirement is, I need to add results/marks of all subjects which are above 40. Also, I need to get total results of all student.

In XSLT, the scope is no longer valid when it loops through the next student. How do I retain the sum of all students in a global variable?

Thanks for any help provided.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26ROW.jpg)

Need to calculate sum of all subjects for all students who marks are greater than 40. The yellow highlighted ones should not be considered for calculating sum.

Comment: It would help a lot if you were to provide a sample of the XML you want to work with.

Comment: It would also help if the sample of the input XML, and the expected output, were provided within the question, rather than as an image on an external site.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is a functional language; variables are assigned a value when declared, and their value never changes.

So in XSLT, unlike the other programming languages which appear to have shaped your thinking, you do not calculate the sum of all marks for each student, or all marks which are greater than 40.  Instead, you declare a top-level variable and you specify what its value should be.  Something like

```
<!--* calculate the total sum of marks awarded to all students.
    * (This makes no sense, but it is what the description says.
    * Mine not to reason why.) 
    *-->
<xsl:variable name="total-marks" 
              select="sum(//student/subject/@mark)"/>


<!--* calculate the total sum of marks greater than 40 awarded 
    * to all students.
    * (This also makes no sense, but it is again what the description 
    * appears to say.  Glad this is someone else's problem, not mine.) 
    *-->
<xsl:variable name="total-marks-over-40" 
              select="sum(//student/subject/@mark[. > 40])"/>
```

It is possible that these variables don't calculate the right thing, because I do not really understand from your description what you are doing.  I suppose that if you want, later, to use these to calculate the average mark, and the average mark greater than 40, by dividing them over the number of marks given, and the number of marks over 40, then they would make sense.

It is not just possible but almost certain that these variables don't fit the structure of the XML you have in mind, since you haven't described it for us.  The sample expressions given assume that each student is represented by a `student` element, which contains a number of `subject` children, each with a numeric `mark` attribute representing the mark given to that student in that subject.